# Как возмоно убрать перезагрузку iframe на странице?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Приветсвую! Пишу на react некоторый сайт. С помощу **iframe** интегрировал страничку, которую разработал 3d разработчик. Соответсвенно, мы на эту страничку поподаем кликнув по элементу навигации. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы состояние того, что происходит на страние 3d сохранялось, если мы переходим по другим элементам навигации и возвращаемся обратно. Само собой, чтобы **iframe** не перезагружался. Буду рад любой информации, которая меня сдвинет с места.

Comment: пробовали размонтировать и монтировать iframe?